# Starting MySQL script file via batch file

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

How does one generate a CSV file periodically to a specific directory from a local MySQL database using a SQL script using a BATch file?  The MySQL version is 5.7.x.

Here are command-line parameters used to execute SQL:

```
c:\...\bin\>mysql -u root p****** c:\...\script.sql
```

This works just fine, but using the command inside a batch file with parameters doesn't seem to work:

```
start "" "c:\...\bin\mysql.exe" -u root p****** <c:\...\script.sql
```

Using this in a batch file, MySQL is opened with the login-parameters, but the script is not executed.

Comment: In the batch file example, why are you using `start`? and is there a reason why you have a closing parenthesis?

Comment: You should not need to use the `start` part. just call MySQL with paramaters like `"c:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p P***** < script.sql`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Compo & @gerhard-barnard! Leaving out "start" made it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Add `c:\mysql\bin\` to your System or user path or a System Environment Variable.  This example works for me, and provides results as a text output:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    start /WAIT cmd.exe @cmd /c "net start mysql56"
    mysql -h localhost -u user --password=password -D database <C:\SQL\myAdhoc.sql>>C:\SQL\myAdhoc-results.txt
endlocal
```